# Check if all numbers in a Python list are even numbers, loop exits after first even/ odd number and doesn't check entire list

Tags: python

I'm trying to fix a script that's supposed to check if all numbers in a list are even.
I can't add any lines, only modify existing ones, if I could add lines I know the solution.
The problem is that the loop exits after checking the first number in the list.

```
def all_even(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] % 2 != 0:
            return False
        return True
```

Found other solutions but they add more lines which I can't because this is an assignment.

Comment: You return immediately after you check the first number. Why are you surprised that it doesn't check the other numbers? You want to return `True` _after_ you've checked all numbers. Unindent your `return True` one level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indent int the last row makes your function abort the first time an even number is found. If you remove the indent your function will return False when it finds the first uneven number. Otherwise it loops over the whole list if it doesn't find an odd number and then it returns True. The return True statement has to be outside of the for loop.

```
def all_even(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] % 2 != 0:
            return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's `all()` function:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

if all(number % 2 == 0 for number in numbers):
    print("All numbers are even")
    return True
else:
    print("Not all numbers are even")
    return False
```

Comment: Op clearly saying ` I can't add any lines, only modify existing ones`

Comment: Still, `return all(n % 2 == 0 for n in numbers)` is the most elegant solution to the actual problem.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Then the correct sollution is to do as stated by Maximillian Schaller, simply outdent the final `return True` line one time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use range for this, because for loop in list will do the work.

```
def all_even(list):
    for i in list:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            return False
    return True
```